# What's the best way to disable the pagination in zend framework2?

Tags: pagination, zend-framework2

What's the best way to disable the pagination?
I need to see all pages and then render the view and get the rendered html.
(In my case It's so slow)

```
$paginationAdapter = new TebipPaginatorAdapter($this->getSmsService(),$filterParams);

    // Creating and configuring paginator
    $paginator = new Paginator($paginationAdapter);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(0);

    $view = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $view->setVariables($result);
    $view->setTemplate('/project/sms-stats/list-sms');

    $viewRender = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');

    $html = $viewRender->render($view);
```

This line helped me to see all rendered html but it's so slow

```
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your adapter **TebipPaginatorAdapter** returns an object.
Your pagination object is very heavy.
To increase your performance you need to change your adapter to array.
http://www.webconsults.eu/blog/entry/108-What_is_a_Hydrator_in_Zend_Framework_2

Native hydrator in zend.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.aggregate.html

+ you need to use a cache with hydrator  http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/zend-framework-2-using-zendcache-and-hydratingresultset-to-save-database-resultset/

It will increase your perfomance.

```
  public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet();
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setObjectPrototype(new Sample());

        $this->initialize();
    }
```

Transforming an Object into Array Data (extract) or the other way arround (hydrate)

```
namespace Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator;

interface HydratorInterface
{
    /**
     * Extract values from an object
     *
     * @param  object $object
     * @return array
     */
    public function extract($object);

    /**
     * Hydrate $object with the provided $data.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @param  object $object
     * @return object
     */
    public function hydrate(array $data, $object);
}
```

I had the same problem in Symfony, and I used hydrator + cache.

Comment: Congratz for the accept. But i'll just say this again: It's stupid and totally imperformant to use a paginator if it is not needed. I'm sure there is way better options to solve the root problem than this.

Answer (score 4):

This question is pretty weird...

Either you want Pagination, in this case you see only a fraction of the bulk, or you do not want Pagination and in that case you'd see all entries.

If you have an Action that requires all Entries to be listed, then do NOT use Pagination, it's as simple as that.

Though in most cases i suggest to simply enable your action to take a Parameter that increases the amount of Items per Page. Listing 100 / 200 / 500 Entries as maximum on one single page should be more than enough.

Comment: I need to parse the html content,that's why I need to disable the pagination.

Comment: What EXACTLY are you trying to do? As i said, it sounds *very* fishy. Here's a nice quote: `You seem to be asking an X vs Y problem. You want to do X, and you think you can solve it with Y, but you don't know how to do Y, but when what you should really be asking is how to do X, because we will probably be able to give you a better answer`